# I looked for it “until” I found it

Tags: translation, word-choice, word

How do I say “I looked for it until I found it“ or “I looked for (something) until I found it” what is the word that i use for “until”?

Comment: 我一直找，找到为止。BTW, isn't this something google can help with?

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E7%82%BA%E6%AD%A2

Comment: Google: until --> 直到 or 直至

Comment: submit "look until find" to online dictionaries,e.g. iciba: 寻找直到找到 Search until you find it. 继续寻找直到你找到它 Keep looking until you find it, google translate:我找到它“直到”我发现它。seems acceptable although repeated (even single) use of 它 seems uncharacteristic of Chinese (cf. 1st example from iciba)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I believe these are the colloquial expressions that you are looking for:

1. 我找了一找才找到。
2. 我找了半天才找到。
3. 我找了好久才找到。

The key word is 才, which is the closest to the English words "until" / "till".

No. 1 is perhaps the best match. "找了一找" simply means "looked for" or "searched", without any indication of time frame.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "直到 [...為止]"

> 我一直找，直到找到它為止。

It's still correct if you omit 為止, but in this case keeping it sounds more natural to me.

"直到" has two meanings, one of which is slightly different from "until":

**1. something is true before the time point, but false after it.**

"Until" is this meaning. For example,

> It's not available until tomorrow. 直到明天才有/能提供
>
> I didn’t know this matter until now. 直到現在我才知道這件事

It's implied that it will be available tomorrow or after tomorrow and I know this matter now.

**2. something is true before the time point, and could be also true after it.**

For the second meaning:

> Up to now I still remember this matter. 直到現在我仍然記得這件事